# JPG file metadata

Tags: data-recovery, photos, metadata, jpeg, pictures

I am trying to get any information from a picture. 
I need the date, name of the person who took it or anything.
I am trying to use some metadata checkers but they just show me the resolution and type of file jpg/jpeg.
Any ideas? I have even tried tools like exiv2 and photoshop without any results.

Comment: If the information was never added to the jpeg in the first place (or removed) you won't be able to retrieve it ...

Answer (score 1):

If [Exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org/) is not able to extract relevant meta data, it could be that data doesn't exist. Not every photographer adds his or her name or general tags to their photos, however much of the default information should be there.

Their website provides clear [examples](http://www.exiv2.org/sample.html) on how to use their software. Try using the `-pt` command like this:

`$ exiv2 -pt img_1771.jpg`

[The utility prints out all Exif information as interpreted (translated) values. Alternatively, `-pv` prints the plain Exif data values.](http://www.exiv2.org/sample.html) (From their website.)